# How to properly run a cron job on a php file

Tags: php, mysql, email, cron

I've a command in my cron job panel - `0,30 * * * *     /usr/local/bin/php /home/aburof/public_html/config/cron/message.php`

this message.php send emails to users who haven't read message notification

but my cron job doesn't generate any error or send emails

but if i open the url directly like `http://www.example.com/config/cron/message.php` then the email is sent.

I've also tried using `/usr/bin/php /home/aburof/public_html/config/cron/message.php` but it gives an error saying no input file specified
What could be wrong?

Comment: there must be space between command "/usr/bin/php/" and file path "/home/aburof/public_html/config/cron/message.php"

Comment: @PravinS sorry the space is already there i forgot to write.

Comment: Maybe is a working directory problem. Does something change adding `chdir('/home/aburof/public_html/config/cron/');` at first line of your script?

Comment: Does the script use variables like `$_SERVER` or `$_POST`? Those variables are only set when the script is run through the webserver, not from the CLI.

Comment: @Barmar No script doesn't use any $_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST

Comment: just check if file exist in specified folder using "ll /home/aburof/public_html/config/cron/message.php"

Comment: @PravinS file exists

Comment: @PravinS 
 
I've edited the command and removed the local from it now I'm receiving an email saying `X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38 Content-type: text/html`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the word `local`
after removing it the command look like this

`/usr/bin/php /home/aburof/public_html/config/cron/message.php >/dev/null 2>&1`

```
>/dev/null 2>&1 // this command is important otherwise cron job will send email notification on each run
```